# Issue in deleting and renaming more than one files in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

I have to delete and rename the files in doPost.but while executing some of the files are deleting some othes are not. When the same code i run in java the operation is succesfully carried out.here is the code i used for deleating files inside a directory.The same below code is i used in servlet.

```
public static void updateRootFile(String directorypath, String appID, String[] appName) throws IOException {
    try {

        FileInputStream fin = null;
        File[] listOfFiles=fileLists(directorypath);
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                rootFiles = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                if (rootFiles.endsWith(".properties") || rootFiles.endsWith(".PROPERTIES")) {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(directorypath + rootFiles);
                    properties.load(new InputStreamReader(fin, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                    String getAppName = properties.getProperty("root.label." + appID);
                    String propertyStr = "root.label." + appID;
                    saveFile(fin, getAppName, directorypath + rootFiles, propertyStr, appName[i]);
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("expn-" + e);

    }

}

public static void saveFile(FileInputStream fins, String oldAppName, String filePath, String propertyStr, String appName)
        throws IOException {
    String oldChar = propertyStr + "=" + oldAppName;
    String newChar = propertyStr + "=" + appName;
    String strLine;
    File f1 = new File(filePath);
    File f2 = new File("C:\\Equinox\\RootSipResource\\root\\root_created.properties");      
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(f1), "UTF-8"));
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f2), "UTF-8");
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        strLine = strLine.replace(oldChar, newChar);
        out.write(strLine);
        out.write("\r\n");
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    br.close();
    fins.close();
}
```

Servlet code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import root.sip.RootSipResourceApp;

public class SendRedirect extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String strDirectorypath = (String) request.getParameter("txtfileBrowse");
        request.setAttribute("directorypath", strDirectorypath);
        String strappID = request.getParameter("txtAppID");
        String[] appNames = {strEn, strAr, strBg, strCs, strDa, strDe, strEl, strEs, strFi, strFr, strHe, strHr, strHu, strIt,strLw, strJa, strKo, strNl, strNo, strPl, strPt, strRo, strRu, strSk, strSl, strSv, strTr, strZh, strZh_TW };

        RootSipResourceApp.updateRootFile(strDirectorypath, strappID, appNames);
        System.out.println("after................");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your static methods are being accessed by multiple Servlet Threads at once.

You can make the `saveFile()` and `updateRootFile()` synchronized to prevent being accesed by multiple threads.

Comment: how to use sysnchorized in these methods

Comment: i used synchoronized keyword in both the functions saveFile() and updateRootFile() still its not working

Comment: Remove synchronized from the two static methods. create a local instance of the RootSipResourceApp class. In the init method of the servlet create the new instance and put the RootSipResourceApp in a synchronized block. Remember, if you modify method paramaters of static methods they are not thread safe.